# Uninstalling program from Microsoft's registry entries, What is this number and does it change?

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I am currently trying to, and successfully, uninstalling a program programmatically from its registry entries under

```
SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall
```

A subkey to this key is the actual program entry

```
\\{71F397B4-D4DA-4592-861C-C90816A0D26D}
```

Now, this has a few values under it, namly "ModifyPath" which I find and call with the command line to start the uninstaller from my program.

My question is, how is that subkey name determined? Does it change from version to version (there is a version value under that key, i figure they just update that rather than get a new number)? What is the name/jargon for it?

I want to make sure if another version comes out, I can uninstall it too programmatically. Or do I have to read each subkey under

```
SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall
```

And search each "DisplayName" value to try and find the name of the program I wish to uninstall. (this seems like it would be very tedious and I do not want to do it, if this number doesn't change).

Comment: The person responsible for creating the installation package (you) generates a GUID and uses that as the key name.

Comment: Thats what that is a GUID? So the only way to account for it changing is to search each entry in that subkey for the DisplayName Value equal to the program I want to uninstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key value is a GUID which can be generated by any number of tools (File->Tools->Create GUID). It is usually generated by the person who creates the installer and typically does not change. There are reasons it can change such as releasing a new major version and allowing it to be installed along side the older version.

If you know the GUID ahead of time you can make a reasonable assumption that it isn't going to change (at least until a new major version) and you can use that as your search predicate.